# html tags like <b> <i> <a> is not working with HTML.fromHtml() when sent to ACTION_SEND

Tags: android

When sending HTML formatted text with  `HTML.fromHtml()` and put into the intent flag `ACTION_SEND` the HTML-formatted string won't be displayed correctly for the default email client for devices like the samsung note 2 and all htc devices. But if i choose gmail app then my html text is rendering fine. I tried setting Mail size to maximum but that didn't help either.

```
String message = "<p><b><i><a href=\"https://play.google.com/\">My App</a> Some text.</i></b></p>";

Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
email.setType("message/rfc822");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(message));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it may useful:
First convert string into HTML format:

```
String message = Html.fromHtml("<p><b><i><a href=https://play.google.com/>My App</a> Some text.<i></b></p>").toString();
```

Then put `message` into `method`

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 
email.setType("message/rfc822");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Thanks....

Comment: No, its adding as plain text

Comment: change `Type` like `email.setType("text/html");`

Comment: I tried that, it will just add up bluetooth option along with all email clients :(